# Correctly assigning a data structure in python

Tags: python

I have the following class:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, symbol, rule, children):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.rule = rule
        self.children = children

    def addChild(self,child):
        self.children.append(child)
```

I use it to build parsing trees; now I'm trying to use this function:

```
def simplify(n):
    if len(n.children) == 0:
        return n
    if len(n.children) > 1:
        for c in n.children:
            c = simplify(c)
        return n
    while len(n.children) == 1:
        print n.symbol,
        n = n.children[0] #What is wrong here?
        print n.symbol
    return n
```

to simplify trees by removing internal nodes that have just one child. For instance:

```
     S                       S
   /   \   should become   /   \
  E     X                 v     X
 /     
v
```

When I run the code, the two `print` statements show me that `n` was correctly replaced by `n.children[0]` , but when the tree is printed (right after this funtion is used), I see the same one. What's the problem here?

Comment: Do you have a sample tree that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: `c = simplify(c)` accomplishes nothing at all; you're assigning the simplified child to a local variable that you do not do anything further with.  `n.children = [simplify(c) for c in n.children]` might be a better version of that loop.

Comment: You could just create a balanced tree by tracking the height. A red/black tree is a balanced tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `simplify()` function, the parameter `n` is a reference to some specific node, and you can change what node it refers to; but reassigning `n` doesn't change any of the other structure.  As a specific example, this loop actually does nothing:

```
for c in n.children:
  # simplify has no side effects and leaves the input structure unchanged
  c = simplify(c)
  # c is never used again so the simplified result is lost
```

There's two reasonable approaches to solving this.  One is to construct a new tree as the result of `simplify`:

```
def simplify(n):
  if len(n.children) > 1:
    new_children = [simplify(c) for c in n.children]
    return Node(n.symbol, n.rule, new_children)
  # and other cases
```

This has the advantage that your data structure is *immutable*: if you have two references to the tree hanging around, you know that rewriting one isn't going to destroy the other; if you have a reference to a node in the middle of the tree, there's no risk of it unexpectedly becoming "orphaned".

Still, it is common enough to see *mutable* data structures, and you could add your `simplify` method into the `Node` class to rewrite a node in place:

```
class Node:
  def simplify(self):
    if len(self.children) == 1:
      return self.children[0].simplify()
    if len(self.children) > 1:
      self.children = [c.simplify() for c in self.children]
    return self
```